# Create-react-app cannot build. it takes long time and then got error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I have create-react-project  v15 and  run  **npm  run build**  and takes long time (20mins)(like freezing) for running build then got this error result.

How to Fix this?

```
enter code heresers/rice/my-app-2/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:246
        if (extractedChunk.getNumberOfModules()) {
                           ^

TypeError: extractedChunk.getNumberOfModules is nota function
at ExtractTextPlugin.<anonymous> (/Users/rice/my-app-2/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:246:32)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Compilation.<anonymous> (/Users/rice/my-app-2/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:245:27)
at Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (/Users/rice/my-app-2/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:206:13)
at sealPart2 (/Users/rice/my-app-2/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:636:9)
at next (/Users/rice/my-app-2/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:202:11)
at /Users/rice/my-app-2/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:241:13
at /Users/rice/my-app-2/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:421:16
at iteratorCallback (/Users/rice/my-app-2/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:998:13)
at /Users/rice/my-app-2/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:906:16
at /Users/rice/my-app-2/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:224:15
at /Users/rice/my-app-2/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:421:16
at iteratorCallback (/Users/rice/my-app-2/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:998:13)
at /Users/rice/my-app-2/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:906:16
at /Users/rice/my-app-2/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:213:21
at rebuilding.forEach.cb (/Users/rice/my-app-2/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:504:29)
error An unexpected error occurred: "Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: sh
Arguments: -c react-scripts build
Directory: /Users/rice/my-app-2
Output:
".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/Users/rice/my-app-2/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: The clue is in the error "extractedChunk.getNumberOfModules is nota function". You're probably not exporting that function properly, but without seeing your code it's impossible to tell.

Comment: this package-module is come from create react app  module => extract-text-webpack-plugin.  I dont know to fix

Comment: My guess is that you should change extractedChunk.getNumberOfModules() to extractedChunk.getNumberOfModules , without the ()

Comment: @MihaiT I have changed as you guided  the result is the same. freezing build

Comment: I am seeing this exact issue - any progress?

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to delete the `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` again to reinstall the modules.
Then try running `npm run build` again.